# Java and Multimedia

Tags: java, core-animation, core-graphics, jmf, multimedia

I am planning to retrieve the frames from a video [mpeg]. The frames captured need to be either .bmp or .jpg images and need to be saved in a folder.

How can I proceed with this approach?

I am a java developer but I don't have any idea regarding multimedia in Java. Can any one provide me with useful steps, or any links for tutorials which work in java and multimedia regarding the above problem?

I don't want to use any installer like Xuggler. I need to hard-code it using some API.

Comment: Do you specifically want to write a Java application that will do this?  Or are you just a skilled user that wants to extract frames from a particular video for your own use?

Comment: the thing which i asked is just a part of my application. But i dont know how to achieve it... i need to write an application for it

Answer (score 1):

look at this great project : [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/)